# Disconnected reconnect failed before timeout of X only on Azure CI

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

My project (angular 11) has about 350 unit tests which runs OK in local.
In Azure CI I get following error very often lately :

> Disconnected (0 times) reconnect failed before timeout of 10000ms
> (ping timeout)

I run tests in CI with :

```
ng test --no-watch --code-coverage --browsers=ChromeHeadless
```

My Karma.config.js :

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: '../coverage',
      subdir: '.',
      reporters:[
        {type: 'cobertura', file : 'cobertura-coverage.xml'},
        {type: 'lcovonly'},
        {type: 'text-summary'}
      ],
      type : 'cobertura',

    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: require('path').join(__dirname, '..'),
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit', 'spec', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000
  });
};
```

I wonder if there's something wrong in my Karma config? Any idea?

Comment: I'm having same issue running on gitlab CI. I think it's related to limited resources (mem/cpu) while running on pod. Not sure why it cannot reconnect and complete the test either.